# how to connect domain name to AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, dns, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple AWS setup of 2 VMs hosting a WebApp. An Application Load Balancer is in-front of these machines. I can access the DNS name of the Load Balancer and can reach to the WebApp. 
Now, I want to connect to my app with a domain name hosted on Godaddy. I tried to simply create CNAME (as no Elastic IP on Application LB) with the LB's DNS name, but it didn't work.

What am I missing ? I tried with godaddy support but already wasted 7 days with not solution. 
I want to put SSL certificate also on ALB. Should I be aware of anything specific in this setup?

Comment: What do you mean didn't work? What does running a DIG command on the hostname return?

Comment: @mokugo-devops it always resolves to Godaddy IP. I believe it is coming from parked entry.
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> cosmitos.in
...
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51042
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cosmitos.in.   IN A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
cosmitos.in.  600 IN A 184.168.221.62
;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 27 20:37:09 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

Comment: If it’s showing GoDaddys IP you need to validate in GoDaddy the records you’ve set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, I was trying to CNAME for root level domain. Now, I created an alias in Route 53 and used AWS's nameservers on Godaddy to forward request there.